# how to put one UIViewController as a part of screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uipageviewcontroller

I need to have a UIPageViewController to make a slideshow of my images at the top of the screen ...i think the good example is Airbnb app that when you choose a house you will be pushed to view controller that at top contains array of images in a PageViewController (i think)

i have to say i have an app that is powered by collectionView and i want this to be on my top UICollectionViewCell...

also i found someThing about using containers but i don know how to add that...

and someThing else is I DONT use StoryBoard ...

```
import UIKit

class ImageCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    let imageView : UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImageView()
        image.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Apple_Watch_Main")
        image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return image
    }()

    func setupView() {
        backgroundColor = .black
        addSubview(imageView)
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0" : imageView]))

        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0" : imageView]))
    }
}
```

this is the cell that i want to add that UIPageViewController

I DID FOUND THE ANSWER

i made a calss like this

```
class PageViewController: UIPageViewController , UIPageViewControllerDataSource{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        dataSource = self
        let frameViewController = FrameViewController()
        frameViewController.imageName = imageNames.first

        let viewControllers = [frameViewController]
        setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    let imageNames = ["Apple_Watch_Main" , "Pic2" , "Pic3"]

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        let currentImageName = (viewController as! FrameViewController).imageName
        let currentIndex = imageNames.index(of: currentImageName!)
        if currentIndex! > 0 {
            let frameViewController = FrameViewController()
            frameViewController.imageName = imageNames[currentIndex! - 1]
            return frameViewController
        }
        return nil
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        let currentImageName = (viewController as! FrameViewController).imageName
        let currentIndex = imageNames.index(of: currentImageName!)
        if currentIndex! < imageNames.count - 1 {
            let frameViewController = FrameViewController()
            frameViewController.imageName = imageNames[currentIndex! + 1]
            return frameViewController
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

and in my collection View i made my first cell fully empty so it was like a window then i added the child view controller and the view of page controller to that cell now it works great

here is that code

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        switch indexPath.item {
        case 0 :
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as!ImageCell

            let pagecontroller = PageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
            self.addChildViewController(pagecontroller)

            cell.addSubview(pagecontroller.view)

            pagecontroller.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height/3)
            return cell
        case 1 :
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "filterandorganize", for: indexPath) as! FilterAndOrganize
            return cell
        case 2 :
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Offers", for: indexPath) as! Offers
            return cell
        case 3 :
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "OfferedProducts", for: indexPath) as! OfferedProducts
            cell.firstViewController = self
            return cell
        default:
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Offers", for: indexPath) as! Offers
            return cell
        }
    }
```

you see in case 0 (my first cell) i added it

and it works great

[image: this is the view]

[image: this is the view when you scroll]

Comment: what do you mean by **sth**??

Comment: abbreviation for something

Comment: @dahiya_boy sth = something...

Comment: i will change that dahiya

Comment: @michealwoods I never used AirBnb App. So better if you would add what is your expected output and what actually you are getting now so that we answered accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote Answer as an Edit And it works great